# how to convert string column to dictionary type in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `events` -

```
|events|
|{'id': 109421132110384, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 28, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'in_reply_to_id': None, 'in_reply_to_account_id': None, 'sensitive': False, 'spoiler_text': '', 'visibility': 'public', 'language': 'en', 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190455'},'note':'<p>Google me. Now go to page 8. Nope, that\'s not me. Try page 12.</p><p>-------------------------------</p><p>Would talk about <a href="https://mastodon.world/tags/parenting" class="mention hashtag" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">#<span>parenting</span></a> all day, if you let me.)</p>'|
|{'id': 109421132340384, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'in_reply_to_id': None, 'in_reply_to_account_id': None, 'sensitive': False, 'spoiler_text': '', 'visibility': 'public', 'language': 'en', 'uri': 'https://users/statuses/10942113190467'},'note':'<p>Google me. Now go to page 8. Nope, that\'s not me. Try page 12.</p><p>-------------------------------</p><p>Would talk about <a href="https://mastodon.world/tags/parenting" class="mention hashtag" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">#<span>parenting</span></a> all day, if you let me.)</p>'|
```

Datatypes -

```
print(type(df['events'][0])) 
<class 'str'>
print(type(df['events']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

How can we convert the string to the dictionary type?

Comment: did you try something like this? `pd.DataFrame(df['events'].tolist())]`

Comment: @JozefCechovsky , I tried this too, getting the same datatype as in the posted question.

Comment: @deepu2711 you need convert string repr of dict to dictionary inside the `Dataframe`? or you need to access the elemnts in Dataframe as `dict`?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you mean by "the string"? Maybe you can consider including your expected result into your question?

Comment: @Bhargav , I need the df['events'] to be dict type , so that I can access id's value from the dictionary created.

Comment: Instead you can split dict to sep columns and then access id elemnts...

Answer (score 0):

Your need to typecast column `type to dict` ?

There is no such thing called `type - dict` in pandas. These kind of dictionary type formats normally considered as `str or mixed` in pandas. Normally as per my knowledge data will be proccesed as vectors in pandas - [Intro to data structures #pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html). Its simply a `dict` sequence stored in vectorised formats.

More simply - A dictionary stored inside an array will never become dict as data inside the array frommated as a `Dict`

[image]

Comment: @jazerial am i wrong? Correct me...It's juts my thought

Comment: No, it is not wrong. But OP need convert string repr of dict to dictionary. It is obviously no problem with `ast.literal_eval`, but here is substring `'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 28, 11, 12, 50, tzinfo=tzutc()),` and it failed.

Comment: how can i access the id, created_at,in_reply_to_id values from the events column which is string type?